# Pure NodeJS and GraphQL, no middleware

Tags: node.js, api, graphql

Is there any example code implementing GraphQL on NodeJS without using any other middleware like Express, Apollo, etc. Just pure NodeJS http server with GraphQL, and any SQL db.

upd: If someone interested, you can check out my implementation on github - [pureGraphQLapi](https://github.com/unstppbl/puRESTapi)

Comment: The problem is that I can't find any such example, every tutorial is using express or alike frameworks.

Comment: What is the problem of express?

Comment: @hurricane, let's say my mentor told me to make API on GraphQL with NodeJS only. I am leak of knowledge how they bound together, and what is the proper routing.

Comment: @altsab I want to know about this as well. I have created a NodeJS server with HTTP module (no middleware like express). Now, I cannot get Graphiql, the nice playground with schema information working. Because there is no resource online about it. Everything talks about express.

Comment: @UniSoundWaterloo Here, as pointed in the upd of the question I made my own implementation, you can check it out here https://github.com/altsab/pureGraphQLapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from using Node.js and GraphQL only ; you will be writing a little more code though.

- [Create your HTTP Server with Node.js only](https://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html#synopsis_example)
- Listen to incoming requests and use POST json body (for example) to pass query and variables to [graphql](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/) function